# node-vibrant package and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

People,
I´m trying to show the hex of a color inside a react Component with node-vibrant. (I have this node package installed)

It´s working when I run it with node from the console.

```
|- file.js
|- image.jpg
```

file.js

```
// I cannot make it work with ES6 importing
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');

let v = new Vibrant('image.jpg')
v.getPalette((err, palette) => console.log(palette.Vibrant.getHex()))
```

CMD:

```
node file.js
```

Result:

```
#2e5475
```

When I move that to my component...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');

class Hello extends Component {

  helloPalette = palette => {
    console.log(palette)
  }

  render() {

    // I also tried here const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');

    return (
      {
        let v = new Vibrant('image.jpg')
        v.getPalette((err, palette) => this.helloPalette(palette.Vibrant.getHex()))
      }
    )
  }
}

export default Hello
```

I received the following error...

```
Error in ./src/Hello.js 
Syntax error: C:/test/src/Hello.js: let is a reserved word (23:7)  

    21 |     return (
    22 |       {
  > 23 |        let v = new Vibrant('image.jpg')
       |        ^
    24 |        v.getPalette((err, palette) => this.helloPalette(palette.Vibrant.getHex()))
    25 | 
    26 |       }
```

And...

If I change and move the var declaration to var v; below the function...
Failed to compile.
Error in ./src/Hello.js 
Syntax error: C:/test/src/Hello.js: Unexpected token (10:4)

Or...

If I change and move the var before the return() as well nexpected token, expected ,

Can anyone provide light...? Does anyone use this or something similar with React...?
Will appreciate anyhelp.
Good weekend

Comment: This is unrelated to the package ... you simply have a syntax error. The surrounding curly braces in your return statement imply you are trying to return an object, but the lines inside are assignments/expressions instead of object properties/keys

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your object first and correct some syntax errors, THEN return it.

```
...
let v = new Vibrant('image.jpg')
return v.getPalette((err, palette) => this.helloPalette(palette.Vibrant.getHex()))
```

Comment: Thanks, @NonCreature0714 I tried that as well receiving TypeError: palette is undefined

Comment: `palette` is passed as an argument in your code example -- but where is it defined?

Comment: Because palette is undefined, I have to assume that palette is actually `undefined`. So, apologies for the repetition, but where is it being defined?

Answer (score 0):

For people interested, you can use the [react-palette](https://github.com/leonardokl/react-palette) package which does the job for you:

```
yarn add react-palette
```

And your code would look like this:

```
import Palette from 'react-palette'

<Palette image={IMAGE_URL}>
  {palette => (
    <div style={{ color: palette.vibrant }}>
      Hello world
    </div>
  )}
</Palette>
```

The package uses `node-vibrant` under the hood thanks to an [util function](https://github.com/leonardokl/react-palette/blob/master/src/utils/getImagePalette.js#L4), so you can have a look at that if you are interested!